# Primary vs secondary HDD slots, what are the performance effects

Tags: linux, windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, performance

What's the difference between the primary and secondary HD slots in a laptop?

On a clean OS install. If I have identical 500gb SSDs in the primary and secondary Drive slots on a M6500 workstation, does it make any difference which one is used for programs and which one is used for storage? Another way to phrase this question; If I only have one SDD and no other HDD/SDD, does it matter if it is in the Laptops Primary slot or secondary slot?

What are the differences?

Standard OEM BIOS
Win 7 pro and ubuntu 20.04 LTS w 5.4,0-165 low-latency if this matters

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about M.2 PCIe slots (i.e. for NVMe drives), they *could* be of different PCIe version because their "lanes" are provided by the CPU and PCH respectively.

If your drive is of the later version among the two, or an even later version, then you get a significant bandwidth difference.

If they are SATA (M.2 or not) slots, theoretically they won't really differ, because they are almost certainly of the same SATA version.

In some cases though, not all SATA ports are wired to the same SATA controller, and one of the SATA controllers might be *practically* slower even when they are all of the same SATA version. (This can hardly be the case in a laptop though. Normally you only get an extra "external" SATA controller on motherboard with more than 6 SATA ports.)

Answer (score 0):

On any machine younger than about 20 years old there will be no difference between the two slots. Any such machine will, at a minimum, have SATA connections and for these there was only a brief period between 2000 and 2004 where there was SATA 150, SATA 300 and SATA 600. Since about 2006 almost every host and drive supported SATA 600 and there is no electrical difference between a primary and secondary drive in that context.

Some evidence of the M6500 Workstation laptop I can find on the internet suggests that it was a machine where some models supported the i7-920 mobile variant, which places the age of the laptop as somewhere after 2008 when that processor was released.

That laptop is too old for NVMe, which had its spec released in 2011, and too young and too high end for SATA 150 so most likely all your ports are SATA 600. It is incredibly unlikely to have the 40-way PATA IDE connector where "primary" and "secondary" was an actual distinction that needed to be made.

As such there is unlikely to be any functional or speed difference between your motherboard connectors. It should not matter what you connect to which port, they should operate at the same speed.

Comment: I still see machines with mixed SATA 6G and SATA 3G ports... sure, they _support_ SATA 6G, but really not necessarily for all ports.

Comment: Thanks all, its circa 2010. No m.2 stuff. Unfortunately it does not have the i7-920. its the i7-620m with only 2 RAM slots. Its sata-300 according to the Intel PM55 chipset 3Gb/s 300MB/s .Still a capable old machine near mint. I was surprised by the errors in the specs still available for it. Went to the intel uP page to find the 8GB total RAM limit. On the plus side USB 3.0 ( 1/2 speed)  available through express card slot.